# 2 IIS web servers on single server

Tags: iis

I have a windows server 2008 R2 that has IIS 7.0 web server, Can i install another IIS version 7.5 on the same server?  what is the difference between IIS on windows server and IIS on windows 10 local machine?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not run two IIS Servers on a single Windows Server. And you can not install a different IIS Version on a server that doesn't come with it. BTW, Server 2008 R2 comes with IIS 7.5, not 7.0

The main difference between running IIS on a server compared to a workstation is that a Windows 10 Pro only allows 10 concurrent connections to IIS, while the server version allows unlimited connections. This is the same for Windows 8.x and Windows 7 Pro.

You can install different versions of IIS Express on various Windows OSes, but Express should not be used for production sites.

Comment: is that still the case, with IIS10 on  Azure VM in 2023?

Comment: @DBJDBJ - Yes, that is still the case for all IIS 10 versions